# Accessing Individual Items in an Array and Adding Them to a Total Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am super new to Javascript and currently a student in a bootcamp and am completely stuck on this question...

"Using the shoppingCart variable, create a function that takes the shoppingCart variable and returns the total cost of both items as the total variable."

The code I am given is:

```
var shoppingCart = [20, 15];

function getTotalCost(prices){
let total = 0;
// code below

// code above
return total;
}

getTotalCost(shoppingCart);
```

I know that I have to complete the function and loop through the array in shoppingCart but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to add the array numbers so that it comes out as the total.. I would REALLY appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Read through this, it should help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve it by [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) in javascript, similar to

```js
 var shoppingCart = [20, 15];
    
    function getTotalCost(shoppingCart){
    let total = 0;
    for(var i in shoppingCart) { total += shoppingCart[i]; }
    
    return total;
    }
    
    console.log(getTotalCost(shoppingCart));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var shoppingCart = [20, 15];

function getTotalCost(prices){
let total = 0;

// Loop through each element of the array 'prices'
    for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
        // Add individual item to total sum
        total += prices[i]; 
    }

return total;
}

console.log(getTotalCost(shoppingCart));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate your array of prices with the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function.

```js
var shoppingCart = [20, 15];

function getTotalCost(prices){
  let total = 0;

  // forEach works with arrays.
  prices.forEach(function(price){
    // Parse your value into an integer to prevent string concatenations.
    total = total + parseInt(price);
  });

  return total;
}

let total = getTotalCost(shoppingCart);
console.log('Your shopping cart total is:', total);
```